# May I use variables in Page TSConfig - Typo3 in order to set dynamic content?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tsconfig

I am looking for a way to be able to set some content dynamically in the layout of a typo3 site.

For example, is there a way to set dynamically the title of the site? 
So, I am wondering if is it possible to define some variables in Page TSConfig area as shown in the following image.

[image]

This option would be very usefull in cases where users are not so experienced to edit this content from Template tools --> Setup.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What do you want to do with the variable?

Comment: U can set the title of the site in general and metadata block. this is accessable by redakteurs

Answer (score 0):

Only admins have access to `pages TSconfig` field. They have access to the template record (and the `TypoScript` module) too.
Therefore you should use constants instead which do exactly what you want to archive.

Have a look at the TYPO3 documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/TypoScriptTemplates/Index.html

Define in constants:

```
 # cat=page type=string; label=Page Title
title = foo
```

And use in setup:

```
config.pageTitle = {$title}
```